# Default values for PyCharm Terminal?

Tags: python, path, terminal, pycharm

I accidentally changed the "Shell path" specified in the Terminal setting for PyCharm and now I am getting this error:

> java.io.IOException:Exec_tty error:Unkown reason

I replaced the default value with the string returned by echo $PATH which is:

> /usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/bin

I've been trying to google what the default value is that goes here, but I have not been able to find it. Can someone help me resolve this?

Notes:
The specific setting is found in Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is the value of the $SHELL environment variable, which is normally /bin/bash.

Comment: Thanks that solved it! Now i'm getting an error on the Python Console and I'm not sure why I'll post a link to it later, maybe you know why that is.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error too in PhpStorm, to fix it simply navigate through to...

Preferences > Tools > Terminal

Under 'Application Settings' click [...] at the end of Shell path and open the .bash profile.

This should grey out the Shell path to '/bin/bash'

You can now launch Terminal.